# Change the field name for Foriegn Key using Code First

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

Not new to MVC - used CodeIgniter on PHP but new to .net MVC5 and EF6.

I am trying to add a new table to my project which has a 0..n relationship to the Identity Management user table (AspNetUsers) which is generated by the project into a class called ApplicationUser:

```
namespace GMSB.Models
{
    // You can add profile data for the user by adding more properties to your ApplicationUser class, please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=317594 to learn more.
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
        {
            // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
            var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
            // Add custom user claims here
            return userIdentity;
        }

        //public ICollection<MasterCode> MasterCodes { get; set; }
        public ICollection<ZZZ> ZZZs { get; set; }
    }
```

ZZZ is an optional collection and is defined in it's own class

```
namespace GMSB.Models
{
    public class ZZZ
    {
        public int id { get; set;}
        public string textField { get; set; }

        public ApplicationIdentity User { get; set; }

    }
}
```

when I run the update-database command in the Package Manager, the new table ZZZ is created with a FK field called ApplicationIdentity_Id.  I would like the field to be called user_id or userId.  If I delete the tables and change the ZZZ model to

```
namespace GMSB.Models
{
    public class ZZZ
    {
        public int id { get; set;}
        public string textField { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("userId")]
        public ApplicationIdentity User { get; set; }

    }
}
```

and run update-database again I get an error message:
The ForeignKeyAttribute on property 'User' on type 'GMSB.Models.ZZZ' is not valid. The foreign key name 'userId' was not found on the dependent type 'GMSB.Models.ZZZ'. The Name value should be a comma separated list of foreign key property names.

If I add userId as a field:

```
namespace GMSB.Models
{
    public class ZZZ
    {
        public int id { get; set;}
        public string textField { get; set; }
        public string userId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("userId")]
        public ApplicationIdentity User { get; set; }

    }
}
```

and update-database I get the error message:
GMSB.Models.ApplicationIdentity: : EntityType 'ApplicationIdentity' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
ApplicationIdentities: EntityType: EntitySet 'ApplicationIdentities' is based on type 'ApplicationIdentity' that has no keys defined.

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: you need to replace `ApplicationIdentity`  with `ApplicationUser`

Comment: GAAAAAH!!! I have spend three nights trying to debug this.  Schoolboy error.  Thanks for pointing out the obvious.